# How To Style The First Item IN My Listview Differently

Tags: c#, listview

I've got a news list that I'm binding to a listview.  I need to have the top story styled differently than the rest.  It's style very differnt so I don't really just want to hide do a visible = false on one div then have another one to style the others differently.

Really I guess I want a custom first template.  I'm just 4.5 with all the new model binding etc.. but I can't think of the best approach off the top of my head.  Suggestions how I go about this ?  Thanks

Code Update :

What I'm askign is how can I go about doign somethig like this, or, something better ?

```
<listview>

  <FirstItemTemplate>

    Lots of text
    Big Image / maybe a video

  <FirstItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>

     Summary
     thumbnail
     tagged caterogires

  </ItemTemplate>
</listitem>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach is to use CSS for this. Your listview is rendered as a bunch of `li` on the page. Assuming your `listview` renders as:

```
​<ul id="someid">
 <li> one </li>
 <li>more </li>
 <li>more </li>
 <li>more </li>
</ul>
```

You can create the following css rule:

```
#someid li:nth-child(1){
    color:red;
    height:50px;
    /*or whatever style you need */   
}
```

​

Comment: it's not just a case of changin the class on a div or list.  Imagine bbc news.  the main news article has a bigger image, more text etc.. than all the sub news items have thumbnails etc.. i want a single list but jsut have the first item in that list styled with different data pulled in from the data source

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i get you good, but maybe its something like

```
li>element
```

at your css